# increment a column going row wise usering sum product function Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Table1 data

[image]

i need  sumproduct of c1 with c2 , c1 with c3 and so on wile scrolling down the formula  like table 2

[image]

some thing like this

[image]

Comment: you can use offset() to do this and link it to the row number using row().

Comment: Sorry @user:8628032 I answered your question incorrectly and so have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the below formula to any cell where you would want C1+C2, then drag it down:

```
=SUM($D$5:$D$12)+SUM(OFFSET($D$4,1,ROW(1:1),8))
```

What this does is it first sums D5:D12, which is the sum of your C1, then makes use of OFFSET to SUM C2 values in your first cell. Once you drag this down, the ROW(1:1) will move to ROW(2:2), which adjusts the OFFSET to capture the C3 values. This is as well true when you drag it down again for the C4 values.

Comment: thank you sir what if i use sumproduct instead of  sum .please 
=SUMPRODUCT($D$5:$D$12,OFFSET($D$4,1,ROW(1:1),8))
i did this but not working